# Where to write common logic in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to write common logic through controllers.
I think I should use `plug`. However I have no idea of coding.

I would like to use common logic for only index01 in FooController and BarController, but index02.

foo_controller.ex

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.FooController do
  use MyAppWeb, :controller

  def index01(conn, _params) do
    ~~~
  end

  def index02(conn, _params) do
    ~~~
  end
end
```

bar_controller.ex

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.BarController do
  use MyAppWeb, :controller

  def index01(conn, _params) do
    ~~~
  end

  def index02(conn, _params) do
    ~~~
  end
end
```

I write router below.

router.ex

```
pipeline :browser do
  plug :accepts, ["html"]
  plug :fetch_session
  plug :fetch_flash
  plug :protect_from_forgery
  plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  plug MyAppWeb.CommonLogic, repo: MyAppWeb.Repo
end
```

common_logic.ex

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.CommonLogic do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(opts) do
    IO.puts("init!!")
    opts
  end

  def call(conn, repo) do
    IO.puts("call!!!")
    conn
  end
end
```

Please let me know how to adapt controller method only for one I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand correctly your question, I see 2 ways of solving this:

**1. in the rooter**

```
pipeline :browser do
  #leave the default stuff there
end

pipeline :common_logic do
  plug MyAppWeb.CommonLogic
end

scope "/", MyWebApp do
  pipe_through(:browser)
  get "/foo/index02", FooController, :index02
  get "/bar/index02", BarController, :index02

  pipe_through(:common_logic)
  get "/foo/index01", FooController, :index01
  get "/bar/index01", BarController, :index01
end
```

**2. directly in the controllers**
- first remove your plug from the rooter
- the in the controllers:

foo_controller.ex

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.FooController do
  use MyAppWeb, :controller
  plug(MyAppWeb.CommonLogic when action in [:index01])


  def index01(conn, _params) do
    ~~~
  end

  def index02(conn, _params) do
    ~~~
  end
end
```

and same in bar controller

That being said, I wouldn't personally choose any of the above.
I would try to do some pattern matching in the `index` function or plug, and not building many `index_xx` functions.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I don’t think it’s a task for `Plug`. While you surely might use [`Plug.Router`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Router.html) to distinguish between `index01` and `index02`, doing something like:

```rb
defmodule MyRouter do
  use Plug.Router

  plug :dispatch

  get "/index01" do
    # common_logic
  end

  forward "/index02", to: MainRouter
end
```

it looks like an overkill here since `Plug` is, according to [it’s documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/readme.html):

> 1. A specification for composable modules between web applications
> 2. Connection adapters for different web servers in the Erlang VM

What you actually need here, is a plain old good function, that accepts a `conn, params` arguments and returns a `conn` back. That way you’ll be able to simply call it:

```rb
defmodule MyAppWeb.FooController do
  use MyAppWeb, :controller

  def index01(conn, params) do
    SharedLogic.index01(conn, params)
  end
  ...
end
```

And that’s basically it.

Comment: I should have explain more detail about `common_logic.ex`. I would like to check login status from `get_session` to know user has login or not. And controllers will be made more. Do I make sense about what I want?

Comment: While this is still possible to implement with plain old good function, if you insist on using a plug, refer to the documentation on `Plug.Router` I linked, it contains a perfect example of implementaing a custom route with plugs.

Comment: While this is still possible to implement with plain old good function, if you insist on using a plug, refer to the documentation on `Plug.Router` I linked, it contains a perfect example of implementaing a custom route with plugs.